# Is there a Groovy equivalent to Ruby's #map?

Tags: list, collections, dictionary, groovy

I realize there is support for #each

```
  Book.findAll().each(){ book->
    println ">>> ${book}"
  }
```

and there's even [support for #inject](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/09/groovy-goodness-use-inject-method-on.html)

```
  def sentence = m.inject('Message: ') { s, k, v ->
    s += "${k == 'likes' ? 'loves' : k} $v "
  }
```

Is there support for #map for Groovy out of the box (without any special libraries like [Functional Java](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Functional+Programming+with+Groovy))?

```
  def list = [1,2,3,4].map{ num->
    num + 1
  }

  assert list == [2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `collect`.

```
groovy:000> [1,2,3,4].collect { num -> num + 1 }
===> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use collect, as in

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].collect { it + 1 }
```

For the case where you're calling a method directly on each object in the collection there's a shorter syntax using the spread-dot operator:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]*.plus 1
```

(using a method Groovy adds to java.lang.Integer to implement the `+` operator)

This operator works even if the list contains nulls:

```
groovy:000> [1, 2, 3, null, 4]*.plus 1
===> [2, 3, 4, null, 5]
```

where with collect you'd have to check:

```
[1, 2, 3, null, 4].collect { it?.plus 1 }
```